# Get json data from from django-rest-api with react frontend into a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, fetch-api

I am new to react and javascript. I am trying to get some data **INTO A VARIABLE** in `react` from `django-rest` API.

I am using this variable in another function using react-beautiful-dnd.

I have the API set up and CORS also set up.

This is the output in http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/column_names/

[image]

I am trying to get this as a json object in react frontend.

```
const getData = async () => {
  let response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/column_names/");

  let data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);  // line 29

  return data;
};
let columnFromBackend = getData();
console.log(columnFromBackend);  // line 34
```

This is the output

[image]

Is there any way to get this data into the variable `columnFromBackend`

I am trying to get the equivalent of this value.

```
let columnFromBackend = {
  idone: {
    name: "In progress",
    items: [{ id: "hjnmkjnh", content: "first" }],
  },
  idtwo: {
    name: "Todod",
    items: [],
  },
};
```

If I declare the variable directly like this, then this is the output that I am getting and what I am trying to get from the api.

[image]

Comment: `getData` is async, you need to await it - `let columnFromBackend = await getData();`

Comment: It is giving this error: ERROR in ./src/components/extra_components/Sample.js
Module parse failed: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
 * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
Error: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)

Comment: Hey can @johnwick can you send me json and what response you want you tell me i can help you because i don't understand your problem now

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your second to last line to

```
let columnFromBackend = await getData();
```

Which version of node are you using?

Comment: react 16.14 node 16.15
I tried this and it is giving an error
RowsColumns.js:7 Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
 * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
Error: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it

Comment: As weird as this sounds, try wrapping everything in a top-level, synchronous function.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to **node_modules/react-scripts/config** and open ***webpack.config.js*** file
   then look for `module.exports` and add

   `experiments:{ topLevelAwait: true }`
2. Then change `let columnFromBackend = getData();` to  `let columnFromBackend = await getData();`